# proof that weak axiom of pairing and axiom schema of specification imply axiom of pairing

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing, axioms

as the title says I am trying to give a (nearly, but not fully formal) proof that the weak axiom of pairing (i.e. $\forall x \forall y \exists p: x \in p \wedge y \in p$) together with a suitable instance of the axiom schema of specification does imply the axiom of pairing. 
I haven't found a suitable instance yet, so this would be the first step to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a 'nearly, but not fully, formal proof' (OK, it *is* fully formal, but it is not fully completed):

[image]

Comment: What software is that?

Comment: @J.G. It's called 'Fitch' .. it comes with the book "Language, Proof, and Logic"

Comment: This software seems awesome! (Though I don't fully understand the notions there.) 
Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @Studentu The 'Fitch' system is actually a fairly well known and well-used system for creating fully formal proofs. Here is a list with all the rules: http://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/JAC/124/Rules-Strategy-b.pdf

Comment: @Bram28 Well, I'd never seen it before. Therefore your link is very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @Studentu Cool. You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

Given $x,y$, let $p$ be such that $x\in p\land y\in p$. Then  $\{x,y\}=\{\,t\in p\mid t=x\lor t=y\,\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x,y$ and take $p$ such that $x, y \in p$. Now take the formula $\Phi = ( z = x \lor z = y)$ and apply the axiom of specification on $p$.

Comment: Thank you for answering!